# Yii2 Listview pagination with ajax

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm studying yii2 framework. I have a trouble when use listview wiget. When I click next page I want to update page  but not reload. but I don't know how do it?
this is url when click next page:

```
http://......&page=1&per-page=5
```

Please help me?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

Do like this:

```
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
Pjax::begin([
'enablePushState' => false, // to disable push state
'enableReplaceState' => false // to disable replace state
]);
echo ListView::widget([...]);
Pjax::end();
```

For more info refer this link: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The trouble is resolved